# Need DNS permission in windows server

Tags: c#, asp.net, dns, wmi, system.management

I provide windows application with this code and able to add DNS zone on windows server 2019.

```
string site = "domain.com";
ConnectionOptions co = new ConnectionOptions();
ManagementScope _scope =new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\root\MicrosoftDNS", System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()), co);
_scope.Connect();
ManagementObject mc = new ManagementClass(_scope, new ManagementPath("MicrosoftDNS_Zone"), null);
mc.Get();
ManagementBaseObject parameters = mc.GetMethodParameters("CreateZone");
parameters["ZoneName"] = site;
parameters["ZoneType"] = (UInt32) DNSServer.NewZoneType.Primary;
parameters["DsIntegrated"] = 0; //false
ManagementBaseObject createdEntry = mc.InvokeMethod("CreateZone", parameters, null);
```

When I try to use current code on web application(asp.net), it's not working:

> System.Management.ManagementException: Generic failure

When I change `@"\\{0}\Root\MicrosoftDNS"` to `@"\\{0}\root\cimv2"` this error appears:

> System.Management.ManagementException: Not found

On my physical path, any permission provided:

[image]

Even I set Windows Authentication like:

```
<security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false"/>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"/>
      </authentication>
    </security>
```

[image]

Also I set permission here on WMI
[image]

Even I checked my RPC, it's works fine

[image]

Also I checked **Register this connection's addresses in DNS**

[image]

Here on [Microsoft Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3322cc53-259d-4c0d-9fbf-41dc51304988/trying-to-add-cname-to-dns-with-systemmanagement-results-in-generic-failure?forum=netfxnetcom), you could to see same question without result.

Comment: the second answer in the link shows that it was a permission error on the DNS server.

Comment: @LinkedListT it's: **Just to finish this one up. It turned out to be a permission problem on the dns-server.** And what I asked is: **Need DNS permission in windows server**, so I looking for the permission. Help me to have permission please.